# Django Mezzanine Unicode Error

Tags: django, unicode, mezzanine

i get an unicode error when trying url like www.mysite.com/blog/category/πρακτικα/ or www.mysite.com/blog/πρακτικα/

but i dont get the error when trying www.mysite.com/blog/tag/πρακτικα/

> UnicodeEncodeError at /blog/category/πρακτικα/ 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in >position 58-65: ordinal not in range(256)
>   Exception Location: /home/vagrant/sullogos-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py in load_template_source, line 37

seems it haves different behavior at categories and at tags

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that categories can have a custom template and tags can't. So in the category case, a template name is searched for using the category slug - the error you're getting is due to an incorrectly configured locale which doesn't support utf8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't understant what i have to change to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Mezzanine or Django, but with the environment used to deploy them. See [this issue](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/616) and [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror) for more details. It's not enough for Python to support a specific locale, but it's also necessary for the webserver to be able to handle Unicode files correctly.

How to fix it will depend on the webserver used. If you're using Apache, for instance, you need to set `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to Unicode-compatible values (on *NIX systems at least you should find them at `/etc/apache2/envvars`). An example would be:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Feel free to replace the language/country codes with another one more suitable for your needs (I used `pt_BR` instead of `en_US` and things worked fine for me). From the error message you're seeing, these settings in your system are probably using ISO-Latin (ISO-8859-1) instead of UTF-8 (which I assume can't handle cyrillic).

If you're using a different webserver, check its documentation on localization/internationalization to see what needs to be changed. The important thing is to offer support to Unicode file names, as I understood.